# How do I write a method that is given an array type NameRecord and an int and returns a NameRecord whose best rank is the int?

Tags: java

For example asking for the NameRecord with best rank 27 would return a NameRecord with that best rank or null if there are none

Comment: Please attempt this problem first. If it's not working post your code, and we will help you figure out what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you need something like this:

```
for (int i=1; i<=4; i++)
    for (int j=1; j<=4; j++)
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(i) + String.valueOf(j));
```

Comment: thanks that should work

Comment: How do I write a method that is given an array type NameRecord and an int and returns a NameRecord whose best rank is the int?
For example asking for the NameRecord with best rank 27 would return a NameRecord with that best rank or null if there are none

Comment: @user2994155 don't just completely change the question like that. If someone else comes here, this answer will have absolutely nothing to do with the question!